# how to find the partial derivation by $ z$ of $f(x,y,z)= x^{y^z}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I think the solution is  f*lnx *(y^z)*lny ? But some don't agree.. I need a second opinion. Thak you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $h(z)=y^z, g(z)=x^{h(z)}$. We have $\ln g(z)=h(z)\ln x$.

Since $h^{\prime}(z)=y^z\ln y,$
$$\frac{g^{\prime }(z)}{g(z)}=\ln x h^{\prime}(z)=(\ln x)y^z\ln y.$$
Hence, your answer is close, but is wrong though you may have a typo.

Comment: Thank you. That is my solution too. I had a typo. :)

Comment: My pleasure. I knew it:)